# Fragment adding - removing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to add and remove a Fragment through a `Button`.. 
Following is the code for the MainActivity.

When clicking the button for the second time, I get the error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added..
```

Where is my error?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button myBlackButton, myRedButton, myYellowButton;
private TopFragment topFragment;
private YellowFragment yellowFragment;
private RedFragment redFragment;
private boolean status_zwart = true;
private boolean status_geel = true;
private boolean status_rood = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myBlackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zwart_button);
    topFragment = new TopFragment();

    myBlackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status_zwart = true){
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, topFragment)
                    .commit();
                status_zwart = false;
            }
            if (status_zwart = false) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .remove(topFragment)
                        .commit();
                status_zwart = true;}
            }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517494/how-to-add-remove-fragment-on-button-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double equals for boolean checks:

```
if (status_zwart == true){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, topFragment)
        .commit();
    status_zwart = false;
}
if (status_zwart == false) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(topFragment)
        .commit();
    status_zwart = true;}
}
```

Comment: even better `if (status_zwart){// logic}else{// logic}`

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code as below

```
if (status_zwart) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, topFragment)
        .commit();
    status_zwart = false;
} else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(topFragment).commit();
    status_zwart = true;
}
```